# C# XML: System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, xml

I have been learning C#'s XML with a project however I keep getting the InvalidOperationException. I have put the code below

```
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(path, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        writer.Indentation = 4;

        writer.WriteStartElement("User Info");
            writer.WriteStartElement("Name");
                writer.WriteString(userName);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteStartElement("Tutor Name");
                writer.WriteString(tutorName);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.WriteStartElement("Course Data"); /*This is where the exception points to*/
            foreach (UserCourse c in courses)
            {
                String cn = c.Name;
                writer.WriteStartElement(cn);

                foreach (UserUnit u in c.Units)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement(u.Name.ToString());

                    foreach (UserObjective o in u.Objectives)
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement(o.Name.ToString());
                        writer.WriteString(o.Score.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        writer.Close();
```

Perhaps someone can see what I am doing wrong. I appreciate any help!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: Creating a user record that uses XML to save an external file. Where the course and its subsections are saved as well.

Comment: When I was learning C#'s XML first time, I spent so much time learning how `XmlWriter` and `XmlReader` works. It is great to understand this first, understand how it's actually working. However, I strongly advise you not to waste your time working with it. Use XML Serialization and classes. It lets you avoid over-coding. The whole code provided by you in a question could be replaced with a class definition and 3 rows of code. Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "User Info" and "Course Data" is a different entity. If it is so, I think you may encapsulate them in one entity.

```
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(path, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            writer.Indentation = 4;

            writer.WriteStartElement("My Entity"); /* It is a biggest one*/
            writer.WriteStartElement("User Info");
            writer.WriteStartElement("Name");
            writer.WriteString(userName);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteStartElement("Tutor Name");
            writer.WriteString(tutorName);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("Course Data"); /*This is where the exception points to*/
            foreach (UserCourse c in courses)
            {
                String cn = c.Name;
                writer.WriteStartElement(cn);

                foreach (UserUnit u in c.Units)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement(u.Name.ToString());

                    foreach (UserObjective o in u.Objectives)
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement(o.Name.ToString());
                        writer.WriteString(o.Score.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Close();
```

Comment: They are both in the User Info entity. It is a very short entity.

Answer (score 3):

XML Element names cannot contain spaces.

Refer to [XML Naming Rules](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp).

Also it seems like you should have one root element. Like `CourseData` should be inside `UserInfo`.

Checkout [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IbwKOk)

Comment: Wow. I had no idea! It does not seem to have worked though

Comment: Really? Could you post what code you had so I can do a comparison?

Comment: @JeremyBeare click on Fiddle link to get more idea. Hope it will help.

Comment: I used the Fiddle link to check and compare. I have made all the changes and it still causes the Exception. If I remove the "CourseData" elemental and all within it, the code works fine.

Comment: Create a new Fiddle and share the link.

Comment: I found the problem. Heinz was right and it was the fact that I had done the encapsulation wrong. Thanks for your help!